# How convert std::vector<std::byte> to C-style raw data(unsigned char**)?

Tags: c++17

It's examle how convert `std::vector<std::byte>` to raw data for C-style function. It's perfect work.

```
void SomeCApi(unsigned char* buffer, unsigned int size)
{
    for (unsigned char index = 0; index < size; ++index) {
        buffer[index] = index;
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::byte> buffer{ 100 };
    SomeCApi(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&buffer[0]), buffer.size());
 
    for (const auto& element : buffer) { PrintByte(element); }
}
```

But how I can provide my bytes vector to `const unsigned char**`?? Me need it for function `SomeCApi(const unsigned char** buffer, unsigned int size)`. My try `reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char**>(&bytes[0])`, but it's not work.
I get exception "Access violation reading location".

MSVC 19, c++17(latest).
My case:

```
unsigned char* sig;
sig = (unsigned char*)alloca(signature_len);
std::vector<std::byte> bytes(signature_len);

ec_sig = d2i_ECDSA_SIG(NULL, reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char**>(&bytes[0]), signature_len); //It's throw Access violation reading location
//ec_sig = d2i_ECDSA_SIG(NULL, (const unsigned char**)&sig, signature_len); //It's perfect work with C-Style raw data and C-style cast.
if (ec_sig == NULL)
    std::cout << "BAD" << std::endl;
```

Comment: What "doesn't work"? The code compiles and should print correct results.

Comment: Code compiles, but i get exception "Access violation reading location". It's memory fatal error.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem.  How are you compiling this code?  What version of compiler?  On what platform?  Can you make the example [mcve], by including PrintByte and the `#include` directives?

Comment: For vectors, you can access `data()` as an equivalent.

Comment: I provide two examples, first how convert vector bytes to unsigned char*, and how C function work with C-style raw data. Me need repeat it for vector bytes, it's possible??

Comment: Something like this? https://onlinegdb.com/ByqRJYkrD

Comment: Yes, but me need repeat it for function using like a type const unsigned char**. For example openssl function d2i_ECDSA_SIG, second parameter for this function it's const unsigned char**. I know that first my example work for, unsigned char*)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide a `vector<char>` to a C function accepting `const char**` you can access the internal buffer and return a pointer to it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void someCApi(const char** c, size_t len)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<len; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>((*c)[i]) << std::endl;
    }
}

auto main() -> int
{
    std::vector<char> buff{1,3,5,7,11,13,17,19};
    const char* buffPtr = buff.data();
    someCApi(&buffPtr, buff.size());

    return 0;
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/B1BSNKyrv

Simple interface to get the pointer to array:

```
template <typename T>
class pptr
{
    const T* buff=nullptr;
public:
    ppta(std::vector<T>& v): buff(v.data()){};
    const T** operator()(){return &buff;}
};

//Usage
someCApi(pptr(buff)(), buff.size());
```

Comment: I know it, but it's crutch.Maybe I can use it without temp pointer variable??? Or it's the only possible way?

Comment: If `someCApi` want a pointer to the array... it is a poor design as a simple pointer would be better, thus the only way to manage it is to provide what it want (pointer to array). However you can create some template function or interface to have clean code.

Comment: And I not remember, if i will use simple pointer like you, me need think about clear memory, or not??? How I remember, i can set after this code pointer like nullptr, without delete declaration.

Comment: I added an interface to call the function in a cleaner way. And no, you don't call "delete" as the `vector` will do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's best solution.

Comment: However, the return value from `d2i_ECDSA_SIG` probably don't implement RAII, so it probably require a guard (`unique_ptr`)

Comment: Yes, returning pointer I replace it's on smart pointers. More C++, less C))